# sed replace versus python replace

Tags: python, sed

The format of the output is the same except that when using python, the output adds a new line  between each string.  Any idea why and how I can do this using sed?

```
sed 's:\x01: | :g'

01.06.2012 07:51:55.135 | 3732 | INFO | xxx | 8=FIX.4.2 | 9=157 | 35=V | 56=xxx | 49=xxx | 52=20120601-07:51:54 | 34=40 | 262=VMD1338537114945 | 263=1 | 264=0 | 265=1 | 
01.06.2012 07:51:55.135 | 3732 | INFO | xxx | 8=FIX.4.2 | 9=157 | 35=V | 56=xxx | 49=xxx | 52=20120601-07:51:54 | 34=41 | 262=VLT1338537114945 | 263=1 | 264=1 | 265=1 | 

for line in sys.stdin:
    print line.replace("\01", " | ")


01.06.2012 07:51:55.135 | 3732 | INFO | xxx | 8=FIX.4.2 | 9=157 | 35=V | 56=xxx | 49=xxx | 52=20120601-07:51:54 | 34=40 | 262=VMD1338537114945 | 263=1 | 264=0 | 265=1 | 

01.06.2012 07:51:55.135 | 3732 | INFO | xxx | 8=FIX.4.2 | 9=157 | 35=V | 56=xxx | 49=xxx | 52=20120601-07:51:54 | 34=41 | 262=VLT1338537114945 | 263=1 | 264=1 | 265=1 |
```

Comment: Could you post the input file so we have something to play with?

Comment: @mgilson It shouldn't be hard to produce; take the output he posted and run it through `sed 's/ | /\x01/g'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a second substitution that replaces the end of the line with a newline: `s/$/\n/`. Since you have two patterns now, you need to use `-e`:

```
sed -e 's:\x01: | :g' -e 's/$/\n/'
```

Comment: Ahh right -- Now I remember why I habitually use `-e` with sed. ;)  (+1)

Comment: This worked only when I added a /g at the end of the second command.

Comment: @user1440188 It shouldn't matter; `g` allows a pattern to match multiple times in one line -- there's only one end of line to match

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a `sed` guru, but you can add a newline at the end of every line in sed using the following:

```
 sed -e 's/$/\n/g'
```

This works because `$` matches the end of a line.  Note that you can string multiple `sed` commands together with `-e` (as pointed out by Michael Mrozek -- see `man sed` for more info).

Comment: so the full command would be: `sed 's:\x01: | :g' | sed -e 's/$/\n'`

Comment: No need for the `/g` global designator because there will be only one substitution per line.  Note: I have never used sed.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski -- Yes, that'll do it, although I didn't post that because knowing `sed`, you can probably do it all in one pass through the file.  And, the `/g` is probably unnecessary.  I'll remove it.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
sed '/\x01/{s// | /g;G}' file
```

Or if you just want to add a newline to every line:

```
sed G file
```

Answer (score 0):

print adds a new line
try this instead

```
sys.stdout.write(line.replace("\01"," | "))
```

Comment: I think the user wants the newline using sed -- not a way to suppress it

Comment: oh whoops... heh sorry misread the question and not sure how to do it with sed :(

Comment: sed -e 's:\x01: | :g' -e 's:$:\n:g' worked!  I need the /g, I was getting no output without it.

Comment: @user1440188 : Welcome to SO. If you found an answers that you though were helpful, feel free to upvote and if one was particularly helpful feel free to accept it.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work